# Apparent oddity in C string initialization: printf and strlen both seem to be in error?

Tags: c, string, initialization, printf, strlen

The overall general question is; Is there some oddity in C regarding string initialization that no one seems to be commenting on that I can find a reference to / Is there some particular Googlemancy term to research an oddity that I have stumbled over / Is it me or is there some sort of "bug" or "feature" in how both printf and strlen appear to handle particular strings in C?

I am finding that while printf is supposed to print a string, it is only printing part of it.  I am finding that while strlen is supposed to report the length of a string, it is only reporting part of it.

Have I found some sort of bug, or is this a fairly to very obscure "feature" of C, in which case, what *are* the details and discussion terms of such a "feature"?

Consider this code, and the subsequent output:

Code:

```
/* Header files for program support */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    /* The primary program section */
int main(void)
{

    /* Variable declaration and initialization*/
    char aitch[30] = "Cat";

    /* What gets done here */
    printf("The string aitch is: %s.\n", aitch);
    printf("strlen says aitch is %lu characters long.\n", strlen(aitch));
    printf("aitch[10] is what is between >> and <<: >>%c<<.\n\n", aitch[10]);

    printf("Now dish out a bunch of chopped liver.\n\n");


    /* More variable declaration and initialization*/
    aitch[11] = ' '; aitch[12] = 'C'; aitch[13] = 'h'; aitch[14] = 'o'; 
    aitch[15] = 'p'; aitch[16] = 'p'; aitch[17] = 'e';  aitch[18] = 'd'; 
    aitch[19] = ' '; aitch[20] = 'l'; aitch[21] = 'i'; aitch[22] = 'v'; 
    aitch[23] = 'e'; aitch[24] = 'r';

    /* Looking over the new stuff */
    printf("aitch listed by character at this point is:\n\n");

    printf("%c", aitch[0]); printf("%c", aitch[1]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[2]); printf("%c", aitch[3]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[4]); printf("%c", aitch[5]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[6]); printf("%c", aitch[7]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[8]); printf("%c", aitch[9]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[10]); printf("%c", aitch[11]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[12]); printf("%c", aitch[13]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[14]); printf("%c", aitch[15]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[16]); printf("%c", aitch[17]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[18]); printf("%c", aitch[19]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[20]); printf("%c", aitch[21]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[22]); printf("%c", aitch[23]); 
    printf("%c", aitch[24]); printf("\n\n");

    /* Hang on, what was that last bit? */
    printf("printf still says all of aitch is %s.\n", aitch);
    printf("strlen still says all of aitch is %lu characters long.\n", 
        strlen(aitch));
    printf("aitch[10] is still what is between >> and <<:  >>%c<<.\n\n", aitch[10]);

    printf("Now put something in the empty area.\n\n");

    /* More variable declaration and initialization*/
    aitch[3] = '_'; aitch[4] = '_'; aitch[5] = '_'; aitch[6] = '_';
    aitch[7] = '_'; aitch[8] = '_'; aitch[9] = '_';  aitch[10] = '_'; 

    /* Ok, _Now_ what??? */
    printf("printf now says all of aitch is:\n\n%s.\n\n", aitch);
    printf("strlen says all of aitch _now_ is %lu characters long.\n", 
        strlen(aitch));
    printf("aitch[10] is now what is between >> and <<:  >>%c<<.\n\n", aitch[10]);

}
```

Output:

```
% ./a.out
The string aitch is: Cat.
strlen says aitch is 3 characters long.
aitch[10] is what is between >> and <<: >><<.

Now dish out a bunch of chopped liver.

aitch listed by character at this point is:

Cat Chopped liver

printf still says all of aitch is Cat.
strlen still says all of aitch is 3 characters long.
aitch[10] is still what is between >> and <<:  >><<.

Now put something in the empty area.

printf now says all of aitch is:

Cat________ Chopped liver.

strlen says all of aitch _now_ is 25 characters long.
aitch[10] is now what is between >> and <<:  >>_<<.
```

Comment: I'd go with "obscure feature". Do you know *what a string is*, in C?

Comment: Please tell us what you understand a string to be in C. It is clearly a wrong understanding. A C string ends at  the first NUL character. Your "chopped liver" code writes to characters after the NUL character so of course it does not change the original string. There is nothing wrong with `printf` nor `strlen`.

Comment: You should mention what you expect to happen. And revisit what a string is. In short: if it is not counted with `strlen` or printed by `printf("%s")`, then it is not part of that string. It might be part of another string or no string at all.

Comment: OT: The 25 `printf("%c", aitch[x])` could be replaced by a for loop which is faster to write than it took you to copy/paste and replace the x by 0..25

Comment: In the first part, `aitch[3]` still contains a nul string terminator, so `strlen()` reports the same length and `printf()` outputs the same string. Neither `strlen()` nor `printf()` are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a *string* is: a series of characters, ending with a null character (a 0 byte).

```
char aitch[30] = "Cat";
```

This declares an array of 30 characters. The first is 'C', the second is 'a', the third is 't', the fourth is null (to end the string), and the rest are null (by default). (Note: `char aitch[30];` by itself wouldn't make them all null)

So you have space for 30 characters. And if you use the space starting from the first character, there's a valid string stored in that space: 'C', 'a', 't', 0. That's a string which is 3 characters long. If you call `strlen` it will return 3 because that's how long the string is. If you print it, it prints 3 characters because that's how long the string is.

Note that having *space* for 30 characters isn't the same thing as having a 30-character string. The space is the space, the string is the data you actually store there. You have 26 characters that aren't part of a string, that you could use if you wanted.

In fact, you have enough space to store two different strings! Which is exactly what you are doing in your code.

And if you make sure there are no null bytes between them, they become one string again.

Note that any "ending part" of a string is also a valid string. If you start from position 0 in your array you get the string "Cat". But if you start from position 1 you get "at", if you start from position 2 you get "t" and if you start from position 3 you get "". All perfectly fine to use.

Answer (score 1):

```c
char aitch[30] = "Cat";
```

Here, the first 4 `char`s in `aitch` will be, in order: `C`, `a`, `t`, and `\0`, with `\0` being the null terminator. Strings in C are null-terminated. Functions like `printf` and `strlen` expect a NULL terminated string and will stop processing the string once they hit a null terminator.

When you write directly to `aitch[3]` you over-write that null terminator.

Comment: In C, `NULL` is a macro for a null pointer constant. The character with value zero is just a null character; it is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

What we have here is a failure in communication---Y'all commenting and answering are perfectly fine, and the answering commentary is quite appreciated.

*The* issue, as has probably also been seen elsewhere, is the surreally horrible commentary on C that is over there, off thataway, Etc., with no way to tell the quality of  whatever without combing through much assorted, wherever one finds it, and testing *everything* by writing out demo code.

A very particular instance in this case is the rather a few book comments, online comments, whatnot, that declare that char aitch[30] is inherently the creation of a string that is 30 characters long, and then one initializes here and there . . .  *According to that*, whether one group of characters or two or more separated is irrelevant, all such is the one string.

Based on *that* definition of "string" in "C", then yes, printf and especially strlen are not behaving correctly.

On my part, I am indeed doing a self driving study of and dig through C in detail, and am having to wade through many such instances of quite crap documentation.  Thus, quite in self defense, I am writing up my own notes as I'm going, with definitely functioning chunks of example code to support all.

---For the comment that a loop could be put into the example code, basically yes, but pedantically, not yet---the notes that I'm doing are currently combing through variables after first starting with functions, and loops will be about a chapter or two further along.

This instance is not going to be the last commenting snafu that I'm going to run into as I keep studying.---And no, I have no idea what the next snafu will be, I just know that there will be one, and then the next, and then the next after that . . . .